# Why can't I see the column names of a table?

Tags: postgresql

So I made some tables programatically and I want to verify it's structure is what I think it is.

```
>Rocko=# \c Rocko
Password for user Rocko:
psql (8.4.4, server 8.4.8)
You are now connected to database "Rocko".
Rocko=# \d
            List of relations
 Schema |     Name     |   Type   | Owner
--------+--------------+----------+-------
 public | Email        | table    | Rocko
 public | Email_id_seq | sequence | Rocko
 public | Test         | table    | Rocko
 public | Test_id_seq  | sequence | Rocko
 public | User         | table    | Rocko
 public | User_id_seq  | sequence | Rocko
(6 rows)
```

So, for example, I want to see the columns in Test.

`Rocko=# \d Test`

`Did not find any relation named "Test".`

Wait a minute?! Did not Test just show up under "List of Relations"? What's going on here?

Comment: what does describe table Text give?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

PostgreSQL converts unquoted identifiers (such as table and column names) to lower case by default; the standard says that identifiers are supposed to be normalized to upper case but that's not important here. So, when you say this:

```
\d Test
```

PostgreSQL considers that the same as `\d test`. You probably have a table that was created with a quoted name:

```
create table "Test" ( ...
```

so that its name is case sensitive and must be quoted (with double quotes) every time it is referenced. So try quoting the name:

```
\d "Test"
```

Comment: Or better yet, **never** use double quotes for identifiers **at all**. Then you can mix case in your identifiers as you please, everything will be folded to lower case and you  will never have to double-quote identifiers or run into error like this one. Of course you will have to rename existing objects that were created in this unwieldy fashion. And of course you have to stay away from [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) - which you should in any case.

Comment: @Erwin: You won't get any arguments on that from me. But it can be hard to argue with existing databases, corporate policies, and other such unfortunate parts of reality. On the upside, it isn't the typical MySQL backtick madness.

Comment: Thank the lord for small mercies. ;)

Comment: Thank you for this! I just asked the same question and then I found this :-)