# Why doesn't postgres recognize my table fields?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I realize that this question has been answered before, specificaly [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910164/why-cant-i-see-the-column-names-of-a-table); however, the solution does not work in my case. I can successfully access my database and table through the "/d" command in the psql commandline utility. But I am recieving a "Did not find any relation named" error, when attempting to examine a field value named question in my table.

[image]

Why is psql not recognizing the existence of the question field?

Comment: Why link to a screenshot when you can paste in the actual text from your terminal window?

Answer (score 3):

> *Why doesn't postgres recognize my table fields?*

Do not blame PostgreSQL, because the fault is your's.You dint understood psql commands commands correctly.

> Did not find the any relation named "question"

Yes, PostgreSQL said correctly.

in PostgreSQL realtions are *tables*,*views*,*sequences*,*index* but a *column* is **not** a relation

- Use `\d` to lists all the RELATIONS(*tables*,*views*,*sequences*,*index*) in your database.

In your case `\d post`(`post is a table(note: a relation)`) will returns table's structure, But `\d question`  is **WRONG**  (because `question` is not a relation,it's a column),So you must use *SELECT*.

i.e `SELECT question FROM post`

```
List Of `\d` commands
----------------------
\dt  - Tables
\dv  - View
\di  - Index
\df  - function
```

---

Learn more @ http://www.faqs.org/docs/ppbook/c4890.htm

Answer (score 1):

The `question` column is not a `table, view, sequence, or index` name, so it won't appear when called using `\d`..

What you should do is `SELECT question FROM post;`